# how can I solve a timeout error, lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, ftp

I am trying to connect to an ftp with lambda (python), but I am getting this error:

> "errorMessage": "[Errno 110] Connection timed out",

My code is

```
import json
from ftplib import FTP
import sys

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ftp = FTP() 
    ftp.connect('host', 10022) 
    ftp.login('user', '********')
```

any idea, solution or advice?? Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Timeout under Basic Settings of your lambda function, by default it is 3 or 5 secs, move it to some 2 min and test the lambda function